# Why td adds extra padding in table?

Tags: html, html-table

```html
<html>
<body style="background:grey;">
  <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="
    background-image: url(https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png);
    height: 9px;
"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="
    background-image: url(https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png);
    height: 9px;
"></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><img width="500" src="https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I don't understand why the height of third zip image is 18. Basically, when I add the image as background,there is no gap between each row (No gap between row 1 and row 2). However, when I use image tag, it creates gap between row 2 and row 3. I don't understand why. Any ideas? And also how can I delete the gap between row 2 and there.

Comment: Lastly, after getting the insight from other developers, I found I could resolve it by simply adding `valign="top"` in img tag. I am working to add template for email. So that might be the best answer because of constrain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<img>` is considered inline by default, so like other inline elements, it has a line height and space for descenders. Descender space is that little padding under each line that isn't accounted for anywhere, for the hanging bits of letters like in 'p' or 'q'.

If you set it to `display: block`, everything will click together.

Comment: Amazing. Never knew about this after so many years. I had the same issue with a <canvas> element. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A `<td>` tag will by default inherit `display:table-cell;` as a style. To resolve this, simply override that to `flex`.

```html
<html>
<body style="background:grey;">
  <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="
    background-image: url(https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png);
    height: 9px;
"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="
    background-image: url(https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png);
    height: 9px;
"></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td style="display:flex;"><img width="500" src="https://s28.postimg.org/yrbcuftd9/zip.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything added through the CSS is not considered 'content' by the browser.

The only reason you see the first two rows is because of the `height:9px;` CSS.
If you remove that you will see that the rows do not appear (0 height) this is because the rows do not contain any content so they rely on CSS to specify their dimensions.

Because the last `<td>` has content in the `<img ...` tag it will display the image with the standard table spacing as this has not been overridden by any css.

Comment: But why the height of last `td` is `9px`? Even when I set height as `9x` for the last one, it still keeps it as `18px`

Comment: The height of the last one (at least from the original code) does not have any CSS applied to it.and as explained better by @RizJa `<td>`'s will inherit defaults if nothing else is specified. These values can be seen in the "Computed" tab of browser developer tools.